# JSF ViewScope beans incorrect hashcode implementation?

Tags: jsf-2

I am developing a simple application on JSF having the following dependences

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

and being a simple page with it backing bean.

xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
          xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
        <head>
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body >

        <h:form>
            <f:view >
                <h:commandButton id="otxMainPanelTextBt" value="click" 
                                 action="#{otherController.doSome}"/>
            </f:view>
        </h:form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Java code

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;


@ManagedBean(name = "otherController")
@ViewScoped
public class Other implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6493758917750576706L;

    public String doSome() {
        System.out.println(this);
        return "";
    }
}
```

If I click on the commandButton many times according to toString source code it should write

```
class name+hashCode
```

but it writes something like the following

```
de.controller.Other@118ea91
de.controller.Other@1e8f930
de.controller.Other@1a38f3c
```

So, everytime we click there is a different hashcode for the viewscoped bean. Is this incorrect? I have tryed with session beans and this doesn't happen.

**EDIT**

I modified the class following [@BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc) suggestion in the following way.

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;


@ManagedBean(name = "otherController")
@ViewScoped
public class Other implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6493758917750576706L;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
         System.out.println("Post Construction");
    }

    public Other()
    {
         System.out.println("Constructor");
    }

    public void doSome() {
        System.out.println(this);
    }
}
```

And I found this output after clicking many times.

```
Constructor
Post Construction
de.controller.Other@b748dd
de.controller.Other@1620dca
de.controller.Other@116358
de.controller.Other@73cb2d
de.controller.Other@1cc3ba0
```

So, the constructor and PostConstructor Methods are invoked only once, and in spite of this the object still has a different hashcode in every call. This is weird because the constructor with no parameter is supposed to be called on a managed bean instantiation, but it is not, so i still don't understand how can be the object created several times?

Comment: Use an updated version of myfaces core. The latest versions (2.0.20, 2.1.14) are considered the most stable. It looks like an ancient issue that was solved in the prehistoric age.

Answer (score 0):

When you return non-`null` from an action method, a new view is created.

If you want to keep the current view alive, just return `null` or `void` from the action method.

E.g.

```
public void doSome() {
    System.out.println(this);
}
```

#### See also:

- [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope/7031941#7031941)

---

That said, your conclusion that this is a problem is correct, but the grounds on which you based off your conclusion, *"incorrect hashcode implementation"*, makes no utter sense. It were just physically different bean instances everytime. Add a default constructor to the class, put a breakpoint on it and you'll see that it's invoked everytime after you returned from the action method, creating a brand new instance.

Comment: I did an edit with the results of what you suggested. Thanks!!